# Saving JsonResult to HttpContext.Session

Tags: json, session, asp.net-core-mvc

Based on this [article](http://benjii.me/2015/07/using-sessions-and-httpcontext-in-aspnet5-and-mvc6/) i am saving my jsonresult like this

```
HttpContext.Session.SetObjectAsJson(multiple, jsonresult);
```

then i am retrieving it like this

```
var myComplexObject = HttpContext.Session.GetObjectFromJson<FileUploads>(multiple);
```

my problem is that i am getting different data when i retrieve it. for example the jsonresult has a FileUploadsID but myComplexObject has a different ID.

when i use

```
HttpContext.Session.GetString(multiple);
```

The FileUploadsID is correct. It is just when i use the GetObjectFromJson that it is different.

Have i done this right? I am not sure what is going on.

Comment: You should not save a file inside Session State; it is not a good practice. What are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: I need to reuse the jasonresult again so I can send data to the database, taught that would be a good way

Comment: No, it is not. You either store in file system or the worst case store in database between pages.

Comment: Why is the way I did it bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it a bad practice to store file in session state?

First of all, HTTP is state less. We like to keep it that way in ASP.NET MVC, so we try not to use Session State in ASP.NET MVC as much as possible unless we really have to.

Storing data in session state is basically storing them in server's memory.~ If we store large amount of data, the server will eventually throws OutOfMemory exception, and app domain will restart.

In addition, if application crashes for any reason, we will lose everything we stored in memory.

*~In web farm, Session is stored in distributed system like SQL Server or Redis Cache to synchronize the session across the farm.*